# Pack setup files to single executable setup

Tags: installation, setuptools

I have an old setup of the old program written on c++ which contains multiple installation files files.

```
_SETUP.1
_SETUP.DLL
_INST32I.EX_
_ISDEL.EXE
SETUP.EXE
DISK1.ID
SETUP.INI
SETUP.INS
_SETUP.LIB
SETUP.PKG
```

I want to combine all that in to single executable file and i want to execute SETUP.EXE when user would run that single executable. Is it possible to achieve somehow?

The easiest way is simple create archive and say to user to to unpack that and to run SETUP.EXE but i am just wondering may be i can create setup like i describe above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IExpress.exe is ideal for your job. Google for samples. It is included in your Windows installation. Just open a Command Prompt and type iexpress.exe - this starts a wizard that helps you getting started.

Comment: If i am just installing manually without IExpress setup it is ok, but after i created setup with IExpress and trying to install that it is throwing an error `IDAPI32.CNF could not be located in SUPPORTDIR`. Setup directory initially does not contain file `IDAPI32.CNF`, but in case without IEexpress all seams to be all right

Comment: If you Google for **IDAPI32.CNF could not be located in SUPPORTDIR** you get lots of hits. What you experience is an issue with your old setup program not IExpress.exe, I think.

Comment: yes first i did googled that, but didn't found any solutions. So because of that issue i will go just with simple zip archive.