# Embed MSI into setup.exe with WiX

Tags: wix, exe

I have a wix installer. It creates a setup msi and exe. The exe will install the prerequisites required before installing the application.

The msi of course just installs the application.

I have users that keep clicking the msi and when they run the app for the first time is will crash because some things were not installed.

How can I combine the msi with the exe in the wix script so my users will only see the setup.exe and not have the chance to click on the msi?

Comment: use wix burn - http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

Comment: If you don't want to use Burn: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625600/600559