# WiX 3.8: Create an .EXE Installer

Tags: wix

Back in WiX 3.7, there was a `setupbld.exe` tool, which could output .EXE setup files. [Issue 4210](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4120/) removed "SetupBld and friends", and nothing was added in exchange.

What I want is to have the simplest possible EXE "launcher", to which I could attach a Manifest, so that it will start Elevated out of the box. I don't want any fancy bootstrappers and chainers, I want a simple EXE. What is the way to do it in WiX 3.8?

Comment: IExpress.exe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625585/pack-setup-files-to-single-executable-setup/7625600#7625600

Comment: If setupbld.exe from WiX 3.7 worked fine for you, why not just keep using it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use setupbld.exe in WiX 3.8+, you just need to copy the following files from WiX 3.7 "bin" folder into 3.8 / 3.9 WiX "bin" folder:

- setup.exe
- setupbld.exe
- SetupBuilder.dll